# How can an ExpressionEngine installation be updated to the latest version?

Tags: update

Simple as that -- How is an install upgrade performed? Links, anyone?

Answer (score 4):

If you're upgrading EE3 to another version of EE3:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/update.html

If you're upgrading from EE2 to EE3: 
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/upgrade_from_2.x.html

If you're upgrading EE2 to EE2:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/installation/update.html